# Reload page with new context in express

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I have a page that lists events, in which admins are can delete individual items with an AJAX call. I want to reload the page when an event is deleted, but I am having trouble implementing it with my current understanding of express' usual req, res, and next.

Here is my current implementation (simplified):

Simple jQuery code:

```
$(".delete").click(function(e){
    $.post("/events/delete",{del:$(this).val()})
 })
```

in my routes file:

```
function eventCtrl(req,res){
    Event.find({}).exec(function(err,events){
         ...
         var context = {
            events:events,
            ...
         }
         res.render('events',context);
    });
}

function deleteCtrl(req,res,next){
    Event.findById(req.param("del")).exec(function(err,event){
         // delete my event from google calendar
         ...
         event.remove(function(err){
            ...
            return next();
         });
    });
}

app.get('/events',eventCtrl);
app.post('/events/delete',deleteCtrl,eventCtrl);
```

When I make a post request with AJAX all the req handlers are called, the events are deleted successfully, but nothing reloads. Am I misunderstanding what res.render() does?

I have also tried using a success handler in my jQuery code when I make the post request, with a res.redirect() from deleteCtrl, but my context is undefined in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the client side, you are using

```
$(".delete").click(function(e){
    $.post("/events/delete",{del:$(this).val()})
})
```

this code does not instruct the browser to do anything when the response from the post is received. So nothing visible happens in the browser.

You problem is not located server side ; the server answers with the context object. You are simply not doing anything with this answer.

Try simply adding a successHandler.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that this is what I did at first, but I somehow got the url wrong so it was giving me an undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this would not be a best practice. What you want to do is reconcile the data. If the delete is successful, then just `splice` the object out of the array it exists in client-side. One alternative would be to actually send back a refreshed data set:

```
res.json( /* get the refreshed data set */ );
```

Then client-side, in the callback, you'd actually just set the data source(s) back up based on the result:

```
... myCallback(res) {
    // refresh the data source(s) from the result
}
```